# Getting the raw value of a c++ ofstream's put pointer (for storage)

Tags: c++

To get the position of a c++ ofstream's output pointer, I call ostream::tellp() which returns a streampos object.  I want to store this value, which may be quite large, into a binary file.

However, I cannot find a way to get the raw value of the output pointer's position from this streampos object.  If I were not worried about this value being very large, I would simply convert it to an integer; however, my file may be a few gigabytes in size.  Does anyone have any ideas for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`streampos` is a typedef for some (typically unsigned) integer type. Despite the position in the file often being called the "put pointer", there's not actually a pointer value to obtain.

On most recent compilers, `streampos` is going to compile to a native 64 bit integer, (i.e. `unsigned long long`, or `unsigned __int64` on msvc++, or `uint64_t` on GCC), which means you shouldn't have to worry so long as you leave things in terms of `streampos` values.

Comment: One one of my machines (a Mac) sizeof(streampos)=136, but on another (Linux) sizeof(streampos)=16.  Clearly 16 bytes is not enough, so it seems that on the Linux machine streampos is a class.  However, I will try converting it to a uint64_t and see if that works. Thank you!

Comment: 16 bytes is 64 bits -- enough for files 2 [EiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EiB) in size. Even if devices which could hold that much were available today, most operating systems use 64 bit integers to express filesizes, and therefore you couldn't have a file that large. Not sure how you got sizeof(streampos)=136 -- I'm not aware of any architecture on which that is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  That makes sense now - I was accidentally thinking 16 bits.  On my Mac (10.6.6, Intel Core 2 Duo) I simply included iostream and did "cout << sizeof(streampos) << endl;" and it printed 136.  Very strange!